# Colour geom_text by a continue variable

Tags: r, ggplot2, colors, geom-text, continuous

I'm using geom_text to add text to a ggplot. I'd like the colour of that text to relate to the value it contains. This is a continuous scale, so ideally >0 get increasingly red, and <0 get increasingly green. However, the `aes(colour = ...)` argument in `geom_text` doesn't seem to like continuous variables.

Here's a simplified example

```
data <- structure(list(rpt = c(109.42, 109.9, 110.38, 110.86, 111.34, 
111.823333333333, 112.306666666667, 112.79, 113.273333333333, 
113.758333333333, 114.243333333333, 114.778333333333, 115.313333333333, 
115.8, 116.286666666667, 116.773333333333, 117.26, 117.591666666667, 
111.553333333333, 112.05, 112.546666666667, 113.001666666667, 
113.456666666667, 113.955, 114.453333333333, 114.953333333333, 
115.453333333333, 115.966666666667, 116.48, 116.963333333333, 
108.426666666667, 108.905, 109.383333333333, 109.88, 110.376666666667, 
110.856666666667, 111.336666666667, 111.82, 112.303333333333, 
112.773333333333, 113.243333333333, 113.743333333333, 114.243333333333, 
114.746666666667, 115.25, 115.753333333333, 116.256666666667, 
116.76, 117.263333333333, 117.75, 111.55, 112.018333333333, 112.486666666667, 
112.973333333333, 113.46, 113.976666666667, 114.493333333333, 
114.995, 115.496666666667, 115.968333333333, 116.44, 116.943333333333, 
117.446666666667, 117.666666666667), height.rel = c(0.189922480620155, 
0, 0.325581395348837, 0, 0.472868217054264, 0, 0.643410852713178, 
0, 0.872093023255814, 0, 1, 0, 0.794573643410853, 0, 0.468992248062016, 
0, 0.166666666666667, 0, 0.428571428571429, 0, 0.628571428571429, 
0, 0.79047619047619, 0, 0.952380952380952, 0, 1, 0, 0.714285714285714, 
0, 0.16044776119403, 0, 0.235074626865672, 0, 0.335820895522388, 
0, 0.492537313432836, 0, 0.727611940298508, 0, 0.932835820895522, 
0, 1, 0, 0.865671641791045, 0, 0.555970149253731, 0, 0.164179104477612, 
0, 0.380952380952381, 0, 0.578231292517007, 0, 0.836734693877551, 
0, 0.979591836734694, 0, 1, 0, 0.666666666666667, 0, 0.27891156462585, 
0), group = c("Unedited", "Unedited", "Unedited", "Unedited", 
"Unedited", "Unedited", "Unedited", "Unedited", "Unedited", "Unedited", 
"Unedited", "Unedited", "Unedited", "Unedited", "Unedited", "Unedited", 
"Unedited", "Unedited", "Partial_promoter", "Partial_promoter", 
"Partial_promoter", "Partial_promoter", "Partial_promoter", "Partial_promoter", 
"Partial_promoter", "Partial_promoter", "Partial_promoter", "Partial_promoter", 
"Partial_promoter", "Partial_promoter", "Unedited", "Unedited", 
"Unedited", "Unedited", "Unedited", "Unedited", "Unedited", "Unedited", 
"Unedited", "Unedited", "Unedited", "Unedited", "Unedited", "Unedited", 
"Unedited", "Unedited", "Unedited", "Unedited", "Unedited", "Unedited", 
"Partial_promoter", "Partial_promoter", "Partial_promoter", "Partial_promoter", 
"Partial_promoter", "Partial_promoter", "Partial_promoter", "Partial_promoter", 
"Partial_promoter", "Partial_promoter", "Partial_promoter", "Partial_promoter", 
"Partial_promoter", "Partial_promoter")), .internal.selfref = <pointer: 0x15c0262e0>, row.names = c(NA, 
-64L), class = c("data.table", "data.frame"))

caption <- structure(list(group = c("Partial_promoter", "Unedited"), ii.c = c(-3.93552369004191, 
-4.48565545498513)), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, 
-2L))

ggplot(data, 
       aes(x=rpt, y=height.rel, colour=group)) +
  geom_line() +
  facet_wrap(vars(group)) +
  geom_text(data = caption,
            aes(label = round(ii.c, 1)),
            x = 110, y = 1)
```

[image]

But when I try and add the colour to `aes` I get an error:

```
ggplot(data, 
       aes(x=rpt, y=height.rel, colour=group)) +
  geom_line() +
  facet_wrap(vars(group)) +
  geom_text(data = caption,
            aes(label = round(ii.c, 1),
                color = ii.c),
            x = 110, y = 1)

Error: Continuous value supplied to discrete scale
```

Any ideas? I'm stumped

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's nothing special about `geom_text`. In general in `ggplot2` you have only one `color` scale and either is it continuous or discrete, i.e. you can't map a discrete and a continuous variable on the `color` aes at the same time.

One option to overcome this limitation would be to use the `ggnewscale` package which allows to have multiple scales for the same aesthetic:

```
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(
  data,
  aes(x = rpt, y = height.rel, colour = group)
) +
  geom_line() +
  facet_wrap(vars(group)) +
  ggnewscale::new_scale_color() +
  geom_text(
    data = caption,
    aes(
      label = round(ii.c, 1),
      color = ii.c
    ),
    x = 110, y = 1
  )
```

[image]